# How to properly connect existing 8-port cat5 data/voice module SAM-V8 and 8-port voice module?

Tags: data-wiring, ethernet

Moved into a new house with two jacks in each room, an 8-port Cat5 data/voice module and an 8port Voice module. Really am still coming to terms with what I'm looking at here. [image: Whole set up]

My goal is to have data/ethernet in the master bedroom. But the data/voice module has no wires to "Mstrbed", ports 7-8. Ports 4 and 6 each bring internet to one of the two jacks in each of "Bedroom" and "Livingroom", if connected to the modem, pictured below. Grey cable (pictured) connects a Network Attached Storage to modem.

A cable installer suggested I disconnect the wires from the voice module "mstrbed" and connect them to the data/voice module mstrbed. Can anyone confirm this?

Also what is D/Demarc? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks to Steve for taking the time. 
Update: it turns out wires for Bedroom & Mstrbed where punched down into the same port, but only the Bedroom outlet was receiving the signal. Don't know why. But I moved the wires from the voice port and those from the second Mstrbed set from the Bedroom port and now both Mstrbed outlets have strong ethernet.